# Numpy finding interval which has a least k points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have some points in the interval `[0,20]`

I have a window of size `window_size=3` that I can move inside the above interval. Therefore the beginning of the window - let's call `start` is constrained to `[0,17]`.

Let's say we have some `points` below:

```
points = [1.4,1.8,   11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,  18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]
```

If we wanted a minimum of `min_points=4` points the solution of the start ranges of the windows (which I found manually ) are:

```
suitable_starts = [[10.2,11.3],[15.5,17.0]]
```

i.e. The start of the size `3` window can be from `10.2` to `11.3` and from `15.5` to `17.0`. *Trivially, the corresponding end of the windows would just be `+3` of the start ranges*.

I am looking for a way to algorithmically cover this quickly with clever `numpy` or `scipy` or other functionality.

The general function I'm looking for is:

```
get_start_windows(interval = [0,20],
    window_size = 3.0, 
    points = [1.4,1.8,11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5],
    min_points = 4

    return suitable_starts # suitable_starts = [[10.2,11.3],[15.5,17.0]]
```

---

*Note:*

As someone in the comments has pointed out there are special cases sometimes when points are exactly window_size apart. However in reality the points are double floats where it is impossible for them to exactly window_size apart so these can be ignored.

These special examples include:

```
points = [1.4,1.8,  11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,14.2,15.2,16.2,17.2,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]
```

but these can be safely ignored.

Comment: If I were in you, I would share your "manual" / "slow" approach, so that there is something to compare against

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't fully understand your logic, but shouldn't the intervals be `[10.2, 11.3]` (because `10.2 + 3.0 = 13.2`) and `[15.5, 17.0]` (because `15.5 + 3.0 = 18.5)`!?

Comment: @HansHirse you're right. editing now.

Comment: Next question: How is an "interval" defined? What's the expected result for: a) `points = [1.4,1.8,2.8,3.8,4.8,11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]` and b) `points = [1.4,1.8,11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,14.2,15.2,16.2,17.2,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]`?

Comment: Typo at the snippet code i guess, you meant to `min_points=4`

Comment: @HansHirse (a) would be [[0.8,1.4], [1.8,1.8], [10.2,11.3],[15.5,17.0] ]

Comment: Can you explain the logic to get suitable starts once again in detail please ? What i understand is , you have an array of floats  and you can slide a window 3 float long, and The start point cannot be less than 4 ?

Comment: @HansHirse solution for (b) is [10.2,12.2], [12.2,12.3], [13.2,13.2], [14.2,14.2], [15.2,15.2], [15.3, 17.0]

Comment: @HansHirse in practice with the points I'm dealing with which are double floats it is extremely unlikely to have an interval with the same number like [13.2,13.2] because the points will never be exactly 3.0 apart.

Comment: @YossiLevi yes I meant `min_points=4` which I have corrected.

Comment: @HansHirse I have edited my post to reflect that the special examples you gave can be assumed to be ignored as they don't appear in the examples I am looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of struggle I came up with this solution.

First a bit of explanations, and order of thoughts:

- Ideally we would want to set a window size and slide it from the most left acceptable point until the most right acceptable point, and start counting when `min_points` are in the window, and finish count when `min_points` no longer inside it (imagine it as a convultion oprtator or so)
- the basic pitfall is that we want to discrete the sliding, so the trick here is to check only when amount of points can fall under or up higher than `min_points`, which means on every occurance of element or `window_size` below it (as `optional_starts` reflects)
- then to iterate over `optional_starts` and sample the first time condition mets, and the last one that condition mets for each interval

so the following code was written as described above:

```
def consist_at_least(start, points, min_points, window_size):
    a = [point for point in points if start <= point <= start + window_size]
    return len(a)>=min_points
    


points = [1.4,1.8,   11.3,11.8,12.3,13.2,  18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]
min_points = 4
window_size = 3
total_interval = [0,20]
optional_starts = points + [item-window_size for item in points if item-window_size>=total_interval[0]] + [total_interval[0] + window_size] + [total_interval[1] - window_size] + [total_interval[0]]
optional_starts = [item for item in optional_starts if item<=total_interval[1]-window_size]
intervals = []
potential_ends = []
for start in sorted(optional_starts):
    is_start_interval = len(intervals)%2 == 0
    if consist_at_least(start, points, min_points, window_size):
        if is_start_interval:
            intervals.append(start)
        else:
            potential_ends.append(start)
    elif len(potential_ends)>0 :
        intervals.append(potential_ends[-1])
        potential_ends = []
if len(potential_ends)>0:
    intervals.append(potential_ends[-1])

print(intervals)
```

output:

```
[10.2, 11.3, 15.5, 17]
```

Each 2 consequtive elements reflects start and end of interval

Comment: Thanks Yossi. Unfortunately, I swapped points with `points = [1.4,1.8,1.9,2.0,17.2,18.2,18.3,18.4,18.5]` and I got `[1.4,17]` which isn't correct.

Comment: that's because I for some reason excluded the `total_interval[0]`, now after editing it's working also for this input

Comment: For the following `points= [1.4, 1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1, 3.49]`, I get the answer `[0.4900000000000002, 1.9]` which is incorrect. The correct interval should be `[0,1.9]`

Comment: maybe you tried running the previous code before editing? because I get the correct answer as you spot - `[0,1.9]`.

Comment: apologies my bad.

Answer (score 2):

So, after additional information were given regarding the nature of the "intervals", I propose the following solution, which assumes inter-interval distances of at least `window_size`:

```py
import numpy as np


def get_start_windows(inter, ws, p, mp):

    # Initialize list of suitable start ranges
    start_ranges = []

    # Determine possible intervals w.r.t. to window size
    int_start = np.insert(np.array([0, p.shape[0]]), 1,
                          (np.argwhere(np.diff(p) > ws) + 1).squeeze()).tolist()

    # Iterate found intervals
    for i in np.arange(len(int_start)-1):

        # The actual interval
        int_ = p[int_start[i]:int_start[i+1]]

        # If interval has less than minimum points, reject
        if int_.shape[0] < mp:
            continue

        # Determine first and last possible starting point
        first = max(inter[0], int_[mp-1] - ws)
        last = min(int_[-mp], inter[1] - ws)

        # Add to list of suitable start ranges
        start_ranges.append((first, last))

    return start_ranges


# Example 1
interval = [0, 20]
window_size = 3.0
min_points = 4
points = [1.4, 1.8, 11.3, 11.8, 12.3, 13.2, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 18.5]
print(get_start_windows(interval, window_size, np.array(points), min_points))

# Example 2
points = [1.4, 1.8, 1.9, 2.1, 11.3, 11.8, 12.3, 13.2, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 18.5]
print(get_start_windows(interval, window_size, np.array(points), min_points))

# Example 3
points = [1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 3.49]
print(get_start_windows(interval, window_size, np.array(points), min_points))
```

(Code might be optimized, I didn't pay attention to that...)

Output:

```
[(10.2, 11.3), (15.5, 17.0)]
[(0, 1.4), (10.2, 11.3), (15.5, 17.0)]
[(0, 1.9)]
```

Hopefully, the desired cases are covered by that solution.

```
-------------------------------------
System information
-------------------------------------
Platform:   Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:     3.8.5
NumPy:      1.19.2
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: For the following `points= [1.4, 1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1, 3.49]`, I get the answer `[(0.4900000000000002, 1.4)]` which is incorrect.

Comment: So any window that starts between `0` and `1.9` is valid in this example. I.e the correct answer would be `[(0,1.9)]`

Comment: A window of size 3 that starts at 0.0 would include `1.4, 1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1` which is more than 4 points and therefore would be valid.

Comment: similarly a window that starts at `1.9` includes the points `1.9,2.0,2.1, 3.49` which satisfies a minimum of 4 points.

Comment: I get your point. I was too focussed on your exactly four point intervals. I have a fix in mind, but don't have time right now to implement that. Will hand in that later.

Comment: Thanks. Look forward to it.

Comment: Thanks. Look forward to it

Comment: Fixed, please have a look.